# RDS farm - RDS servers "Online - Access denied"

Tags: remote, rds

EDIT - This is on Microsoft Server 2016

I need some help - Our RDS farm contains... 2 rdsBrokers, 1 rdsLicense and 6 RDS servers.

I do have a problem with the permissions to the RDS server rds02-03-04-05 and rds06. But not for RDS01? As you guys see on the screenshot I see rds1 with CAPS and a IP address!

But how do I change the credentials?

I have tried to right-click and click Manage As... and then use a wmirdslic account which is local admin. And it works, but it does not save. After I close Server Manager and open again, its back to Online - Access denied.

Do I really have to remove the who RDS collection and re-add them?

This is how it always look! As you see RDS01 is online and accessible

[rdslic01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqURb.png)

And this is after I right-click and click Manage As... and login with a local admin user on the rds05 - As you see we now get a IP and the rds05 is now RDS05 with CAPS

[rdslic02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0BsG.png)

My problem is it does not save the Credentions i put into Manage As...

Comment: you should also add, which Os have been used imho

Comment: This is done now, sorry

Answer (score 0):

This is solved!

I found out that it was the user that I logged into the Broker01 and Broker02 needed to be local admin on all the 6 RDS servers...